# Передача двумерного массива в аргумент функции

Tags: массивы

Изучаю С(не С++ пока) по Шильдту, дошел до указателей, далее пошли массивы. С одномерными массивами вроде все понятно, различия в синтаксисе тоже. Но как пошли двумерные массивы, то начались трудности. У меня вопрос: Как передать двумерный массив функции? Вот например для одномерного есть три способа с точки зрения синтаксиса: как массив определенного или неопределенного размера или через указатель, ведь имя массива есть адрес его 1 элемента. Двумерный массив расположен непрерывно в памяти. Его можно представить как матрицу. Мне важно понять этот момент, ибо дальше вряд ли что-то получится. Я вообще хотел заняться веб-программированием, но мозги тоже надо развивать, и С как раз подходит для этого. 
Вот есть фрагмент моей программы. Выдается ошибка(см. ниже). Объясните мне, пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка. дайте, пожалуйста ссылку, где разжевывается про двумерные массивы и как их передавать в функцию через указатели. Я изучаю С. Говорите, пожалуйста, в рамках С, а не С++. Просто я думал, что array[m] = &array[m][0] и решил действовать по аналогии с одномерными массивами, но компилятор ругается на меня.

```
#include <stdio.h>   
void screen (int **matrix, int size1, int size2);
int main()
{
    int m, n, i1, j1;
    scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);
    int array[m][n];
    for (i1 = 0; i1 < m; i1++)
    {
        for(j1 = 0; j1 < n; j1++)
        {
        array[i1][j1] = i1 + j1;
        printf("%3d", array[i1][j1]);
        }
    }
    screen(array[m], m, n);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

void screen(int **matrix, int size1, int size2)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < size1; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < size2; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = i + j;
            printf("%3d", matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
    [Error] cannot convert 'int*' to 'int**' for argument '1' to 'void screen(int**, int, int)'
```

Comment: https://www.ideone.com/HXOLjv

Comment: Простите, а можно в функцию screen передать двумерный массив как-то с помощью указателя или указателей на массив? Спасибо, Вам, большое за исправленную версию!

Comment: Просто для меня важно именно башкой понять, что тут происходит!

Comment: Можно так: `screen((int *)array, m, n)` или так: `screen(array[0], m, n)`.

Comment: Смотрите, вот &array[0][0] <=> array[0] с точки зрения синтаксиса, а (int *) array - это указатель типа int на двумерный массив array[m][n]? А нельзя ли написать в функции matrix указатель на массив, то есть int (*matrix)[]? Разве не так правильно?

Comment: Указатель на массив какого размера? Указатель должен знать размер элемента на который он ссылается, чтобы операция `matrix[i]` могла работать.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое! Сейчас еще обмозгую.